# Is there a formula for finding the number of divisors of $n$ without factorize it?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that the number of divisors of $n$, $d(n)$ is $$d(n) = \Pi_{i=1}^k (a_i+1)$$ where each $a_i$ is the exponent of each prime factor of $n$. My question is: can I calculate $d(n)$ without know the factorization of $n$? something like a closed form that depends only on $n$?

Comment: (The factorization is itself something that "depends only on $n$"..)

Comment: In principle one might be able to determine the "structure" of $n$ (the $a_i$ such that $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$) without knowing the $p_i$. Conceivably (but I am not holding my breath) there might be a probabilistic procedure that, with high probability, determines that structure. There certainly is such an algorithm for determining whether the number of divisors is $2$!

Comment: @AndréNicolas In fact, there is a pretty fast (time complexity-wise) algorithm which, given $n$, tells us whether $d(n)$ is a prime! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a formula, but it is sort of a mess:

$$d(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\lfloor \exp\left(k\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor-n\right) \right\rfloor.\tag1$$

Below is a proof of $(1)$.

Define the functions
$$\begin{align}
a(x)&=\lfloor\exp(-x)\rfloor,\\
b(n,k)&=n-k\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor,\\
i(n,k)&=a(b(n,k)).
\end{align}$$
First, notice that $a(0)=1$, and $a(x)=0$ for all $x\ge1$.

Next, notice that if $n=mk$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$, then $$b(n,k)=b(mk,k)=mk-k\lfloor m\rfloor=mk-mk=0.$$
On the other hand, if $n=mk+j$ for $m,j\in\Bbb N$, $1\le j<k$, we have
$$\begin{align}
b(n,k)&=b(mk+j,k)\\
&=mk+j-k\left\lfloor\frac{mk+j}{k}\right\rfloor\\
&=mk+j-k\left\lfloor m+\frac{j}{k}\right\rfloor\\
&=mk+j-mk\\
b(n,k)&=j\\
\Rightarrow b(n,k)&\ge1.
\end{align}$$
So, if $n=mk$, then $$i(n,k)=a(b(n,k))=a(0)=1,$$
and if $n=mk+j$, then $$i(n,k)=a(b(n,k))=a(j)=0,$$
so we have
$$i(n,k)=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } k|n\\
0, & \text{otherwise}. 
\end{cases}
$$

Then if we sum $i(n,k)$ over $1\le k\le n$ we get $+1$ for every divisor of $n$ and $+0$ for all non-divisors. Thus
$$d(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}i(n,k).$$

Comment: The formula entails the determination of whether $n/k$ is an integer, for each $k=1,...,n$. That's pretty much the same as factorizing $n$.

Comment: @JohnBentin that's true, but it is an explicit formula that one could just plug into a computer. Change the value of $m$ [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pxraqnrln9) to see how quickly a computer can do it